# How to mask a specified field in a table when I query it using big query?

Tags: cloud, data-masking, sensitive-data, google-cloud-dlp, sql-masking

I want to mask a specified field in a table when I query it using big query. For example: a table named employee has `email-id` column, so when I query the table all the `email-id` field should be masked with ****.

How can I do it using DLP in google?

Comment: Does this article helps you? https://cloud.google.com/solutions/validating-de-identified-data-bigquery-re-identifying-pii-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, there isn't a way to do this with Cloud DLP/Bigquery during the time of the query.

Possible work around options

- You could create a de-identified copy of your table and query that instead
- You could use column level acls to hide this column from folks who shouldn't see the email addresses https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/column-level-security-intro